# How to use Appium locators when using Protractor+Appium for hybrid application

Tags: protractor, native, appium

I'm using Protractor and `Appium` in order to test a hybrid application.i need to click on an native element.i am inspecting it with `Appium` inspector as i am not able to inspect it with chrome. i tried with different locators also like id and `xpath`.

**This is the code:**

```
var thanks = browser.driver.findElement(By.id('android:id/button1'));
thanks.click();
```

**or**

```
var thanks = browser.driver.findElement(By.id(' //android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[3]/android.widget.Button[1]'));
thanks.click();
```

**Error Message:**

```
Failed: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

I'm new in the protractor. I have found many question here but they all are unanswered. Please let me know if there is anything needed here like switching the context or something which i am missing here.